# Share variables between parent and child directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have 2 directives, one directive that represents a list of data, while the other one represents the controls necessary filter that list.  Something like this..

```
  <item-list data-items="items">
    <list-filters></list-filters>
  </item-list>
```

What I'd like to do is have the parent directive, the "`itemList`", maintain some filter object in it's scope, and then have the child directive modify that object directly, via the link function.

Here are the 2 directives

```
app.directive('itemList', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      items: '='
    },
    transclude:true,
    controller: function($scope){

      $scope.filter = {};

      $scope.add = function(){
        var length = $scope.items.length+1;
        $scope.items.push({
          id: length,
          name: 'item' + length
        });
      };
    },
    templateUrl: 'list.html'
  };
}); 

app.directive('listFilters', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'list-filters.html',
    require: '^itemList',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, itemList){

      itemList.$watch('items', function(){
        scope.items = itemList.items;
      });


      scope.change = function(item){
        console.log('change', item);
        itemList.filter = item;
      };

      scope.filter = itemList.filter; // ?? why can't I do this

    }
  }
});
```

I can't figure out how to grab that filter object from the `itemList` directive, any suggestions?

http://plnkr.co/edit/mVSoxqpeYhwpMxYJFNwj?p=info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter itemList in your link function is the actual controller object, what you want is to create an interface in item-list that allows to modify the filter variable.

```
app.directive('itemList', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      items: '='
    },
    transclude:true,
    controller: function($scope){
      $scope.filter 
      $scope.add = function(){
        var length = $scope.items.length+1;
        $scope.items.push({
          id: length,
          name: 'item' + length
        });
      };

      this.updateFilterList = function(newList){
          $scope.apply(function(){$scope.filter = newList;});
      }
    },
    templateUrl: 'list.html'
  };
}); 




app.directive('listFilters', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'list-filters.html',
    require: '^itemList',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, itemList){

      itemList.$watch('items', function(){
        scope.items = itemList.items;
      });


      scope.change = function(item){
        console.log('change', item);
        itemList.updateFilterList(item);
      };

      //call the interface to update the filter list with whatever new object
      itemList.updateFilterList( scope.filter );
    }
  }
});
```

You get the idea, its basically to create some interface in the parent controller that allows to modify its state, and have the child directive utilize that interface.

Answer (score 0):

Your "listFilters" directive does not create a new scope, so you should be able to just access the $scope.filters object that you're setting in the itemList controller with simply "`scope.filters`" in the listFilters directive's link function.

Answer (score 0):

I modified a little your code
See http://plnkr.co/edit/QF6p3JXQD3zT6Yio2f4U?p=preview
Your child directive scope have access to properties of parent directive.
But if you change propeties of child directive, properties of parent directive do not change their values automatically.
So you should manually change properties of parent scope if there is a change in child scope:

```
scope.$watch('filter', function(val, oldval) {
        scope.$parent.filter = val;
      })
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, sorry it took so long to get back to you.  This solution works, but scope.$parent may give inconsistent results wouldn't it, depending on where it's declared?

Comment: If your `listFilters` directive is always used inside `itemList` directive, then it's OK